# What is best best way to sort values by categories in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I am trying to manipulate incoming data in a very specific way, here is an example where the starting variables `yIn` and `xIn` need to be manipulated/mapped to the ending variables `yOut` and `xOut`. `yIn` is a table column for categorical data and `xIn` is a table column with continuous (numeric) data.

```
xIn = ['cat1', 'cat1', 'cat2', 'cat4', 'cat3', 'cat2', 'cat1', 'cat1', 'cat4']
yIn = [1, 3, 4, 8, 2, 6, 3, 8, 5]

xOut = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat4', 'cat3']
yOut = [
    [1, 3, 3, 8],
    [4, 6],
    [5, 8],
    [2]
    ]
```

I know that `xOut = [...new Set(xIn)]` however mapping each `yIn` number to the right place in the `yOut` nested array I am finding more tricky. I am thinking perhaps a nested loop that iterates through each `xOut` value and checks whether it matches each `xIn` value, and if it does pushing the `yIn` to an initialized array of some sort. This would give me the right order of numbers in `yOut`, but not in the nested array format I need.

If anyone has any solutions (elegant or otherwise) I would be interested to hear them!

NOTE: I do not know the number of categories that will be present in `xIn`. I'm using this to turn two user-selected columns in a table (one categorical and one numerical) into a series of box plots, one box plot for each category.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) & [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const xIn = ['cat1', 'cat1', 'cat2', 'cat4', 'cat3', 'cat2', 'cat1', 'cat1', 'cat4'],
yIn = [1, 3, 4, 8, 2, 6, 3, 8, 5],

xOut = [...new Set(xIn)],
yOut = xOut.map( // For each unique category
  cat => yIn.filter((_, i) => xIn[i] === cat) // Filter items with a matching index
);

console.log(xOut, yOut);
```

Comment: It's quite concise. But it's an expensive cost in terms of `time complexity` for the `filter` method of each `xOut`'s item

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build `category_and_number_mapping`. The structure looks like this

```
{"cat1":[1,3,3,8],"cat2":[4,6],"cat4":[8,5],"cat3":[2]}
```

After that, use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array of each `xOut` based on the output of `category_and_number_mapping.`

In this way, the `time complexity` is just *liner time*

```js
const xIn = ['cat1', 'cat1', 'cat2', 'cat4', 'cat3', 'cat2', 'cat1', 'cat1', 'cat4'];
const yIn = [1, 3, 4, 8, 2, 6, 3, 8, 5];

const xOut = [...new Set(xIn)];
const category_and_number_mapping = xIn.reduce((acc, cat, index) => {
  acc[cat] ??= [];
  acc[cat].push(yIn[index]);
  
  return acc;
}, {})
const yOut = xOut.map(cat => category_and_number_mapping[cat]);
console.log({xOut, yOut});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map has a nice table showing why you shouldn't abuse objects as `Map`s

Comment: To me, it's not bad to use `Map` in this case. What did you concern about? @georg

Comment: I like the use of `Nullish coalescing operator (??)` +1, but I guess IE doesn't support it. And why don't you wrap the resulting object from `reduce` in `Object.values()` and get `yOut` in a single line instead of again mapping?

Comment: You're right. But to me, wrapping multiple lines into one make it hard to debug. Although the result is the same as you said :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help ^^! @Jack Atkinson https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array `reduce` method and create a `Map` and then extract out the map values into an array.

```js
const xIn = ["cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat4", "cat3", "cat2", "cat1", "cat1", "cat4"];
const yIn = [1, 3, 4, 8, 2, 6, 3, 8, 5];

const xOut = [...new Set(xIn)];
const yOut = Array.from(
  xIn
  .reduce(
    (m, x, i) => (m.has(x) ? m.get(x).push(yIn[i]) : m.set(x, [yIn[i]]), m),
    new Map()
  )
  .values()
);

console.log(xOut);
console.log(yOut);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @JackAtkinson

Comment: Thanks!! Thats exactly what I'm looking for. Do you know if this also mitigate the time complexity of the other answer here by avoiding the filter method?

Comment: @JackAtkinson Ya, it does mitigate that issue, it is more performant than using filter. Consider accepting this as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to indicate that your issue has been resolved. Thanks!